# LookUp(User) field is not showing in Matching Rule Criteria

Tags: duplicate-management

I am trying to create a matching rule for one of my custom object.In Matching rule criteria I want to add SalesPerson field which is lookup(User) field on custom object but somehow I can not find lookup field in matching rule criteria.I am aware that Max 1 lookup field can be used per matching rule and this is the only lookup field I have on Custom object.I tried to create another lookup(Field) on same custom object and it shows in Matching Rule criteria.

**Is Lookup(User) field is unsupported in Matching Rule?**

Comment: Query: Is it master-detail relationship between custom object and User?

Comment: No its a lookup relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Criteria for creating a Matching Rule](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=matching_rule_matching_criteria.htm&language=en_US&type=0):

> 1) Indicates which field to compare. When selecting fields, keep in mind that:
>   The available fields depend on which object the matching rule applies to and include both standard and custom fields..
>
> 2) The supported input field types are email, lookup relationship, master-detail relationship, number, phone, standard picklists, custom picklists (single-select only), text, and URL.
>
> 3) An auto-numbered lookup or master-detail relationship field can’t be used in a matching rule.
>
> 4) If you enable State and Country picklists for your organization, we recommend using State/Province Code and Country Code in your matching rules. These fields yield better duplicate detection results than the state and country text fields.

I tried your scenario by creating a 2 LookUp's namely; `User` & `light002__Deal__c` in my Lead Object. I found that if your Look up relationship has auto-numbered as per 3rd point above, it doesn't show in the matching rules.

That's why you're not able to see `User` (Name is derived at runtime) field whereas you can see other Look up fields which don't have auto-numbered fields.

I tried creating formula field `light002_assign_to_formula` as well, but at present **formula fields are not supported in matching rules**. Here is idea posted on Salesforce: [Allow use of custom formula field while creating Matching Rule](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DlULAA0)

Below is the snapshot for the same:

**Lead Object**:
[image]

**Matching Rule**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for info.It looks like I have only one option left here,to create a text field and copy the value of lookup field into text field on Before Insert & Before Update event.This would work because we need to add user or user's id in matching criteria.

Comment: Also Could you please explain which auto number field User object has? I can not see any auto numbered field on user object.

Comment: @DhananjayPatil I don't know actually, What I concluded is that `Name` field is derived automatically. Even if you edit any user, you can't edit `Name` field. It's always derived from `First Name` and `Last Name`.